# Не понимаю область видимости с словарями

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, область-видимости

Есть такая функция в коде:

```py
def on_group(_, callback_query):
    msg = callback_query.message
    print(group_names)
    group_id.clear()
    with open(groups_path, "r") as my_file:
        group_names = json.load(my_file)
    for i in group_names:
        group_id.append(group_names[i])
```

Group_names и group_id объявлены как словарь и список в начале кода.
В строке 3 выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kolch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\dispatcher.py", line 242, in handler_worker
    await self.loop.run_in_executor(
  File "C:\Users\kolch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\kolch\Desktop\all\Prog\py\Group_filter\filter_main.py", line 132, in on_group
    print(group_names)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'group_names' referenced before assignment
```

Проблема с видимостью переменных или что?

Comment: Вы хотели сказать, область видимости переменных в функции? Для того, чтобы использовать объявленные вне функции переменные, их нужно явное передать в функцию. Например def on_group(group_names). В противном случае переменные с одинаковым названием, но объявленные на разных уровнях - разные переменные.

Comment: @strawdog Функция вызывается не мной а библиотекой pyrogram и я не могу менять входящие параметры в функцию

Comment: Ну объявите в начале функции `global group_names`. Это плохая практика использовать глобальные переменные, но для начала сойдёт. Если бы вы ничего не присваивали в `group_names`, то питон бы взял значение из глобальной переменной автоматически и успокоился. А поскольку вы меняете эту переменную внутри функции, то она автоматически считается локальной и её глобальность нужно явно объявлять.

Comment: @CrazyElf Global или nonlocal не работает с словарями, я пробовал

Comment: @Kripl Не может такого быть. Возможно, `group_names` - это переменная класса? Тогда и обращение к ней другое должно быть. Покажите, где она впервые у вас появляется. Добавьте код в вопрос - внутри чего и как появляется впервые `group_names`.

Comment: @CrazyElf Нет просто ```group_names = {}```

Comment: @Kripl Не внутри какого-то класса этот код, точно? Тогда `global` должен работать. Показывайте код. И вашу попытку с `global` тоже показывайте и какая ошибка в этом случае. Добавьте это всё в вопрос под уже имеющимся кодом и текстом, вреда не будет, только польза.

Comment: @CrazyElf добавил UPD в ответ, почему `global` не помогал, все дело в создании новой переменной с тем же именем внутри функции и вызовом `print` до этого присваивания

Comment: @Dmitry В ответ, а не в вопрос )  Ну, вообще не надо всё домысливать за автора вопроса, если он нам не хочет помогать решать его вопрос, то наука тут бессильна.

Comment: @CrazyElf да, я уже вчера сдавался и бросал эту затею, потом собрал мысли и попытался объяснить))

Answer (score 1):

вот так работать будет, но не является хорошей практикой

```py
group_names = {}

def on_group():
    print(group_names)


on_group()
```

То же самое, но верное использование

```py
def on_group(param):
    print(param)


group_names = {}
on_group(group_names)
```

Основной принцип: функция не должна работать с переменными вне зоны ее видимости и глобальными переменными. Все необходимые данные функция получает на вход, все что было изменено возвращается из функции через `return`

А вот так работать не будет

```py
def on_group():
    print(group_names)


on_group()
```

**UPD START**

И вот так работать не будет

```py
def on_group():
    print(group_names)
    group_names = {1:"name"}


group_names = {}
on_group()
```

Во втором случае, если вы используете оператор присваивания, создается переменная внутри области видимости фунции. При загрузке вашей функции интерпретатор решает, что глобальная область видимости для `group_names` не должна использоваться внтури локальной области видимости функции, что и приводит к ошибке, когда вы пытаетесь сослаться на переменную до того, как она будет назначена локально.

Если же, вы не будете присваивать (полностью перезаписывать словарь), а просто будете его менять, добавляя или изменяя его, то все будет работать

```py
def on_group():
    print(group_names)
    group_names[1] = "name"


group_names = {}
on_group()
```

**UPD END**

может вот так будет понятна моя мысль, про не использование переменных вне области видимости функции

```py
def on_group(_, callback_query):
    msg = callback_query.message
    group_id.clear()
    with open(groups_path, "r") as my_file:
        group_names = json.load(my_file)
    for i in group_names:
        group_id.append(group_names[i])
    return group_names


group_names = {}
group_names = on_group(_, query)
```

Comment: group_names это словарь и он определён до вызова функции

Comment: @Kripl вот так и не должно быть, почему вы не хотите передать этот словарь в функцию, зачем вы его переопределяете в конструкции `with`?

Comment: Я перезаписываю словарь забирая значение из файла

Comment: @Kripl добавьте код в сам вопрос с определением данной переменной

Comment: ```group_names = {}```

Comment: @Kripl я сдаюсь, может вам кто-то еще сможет пояснить